# On click, slide div down and change button icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to slide a div down from the top of the page when clicking a button - and also change the icon on the button. Then on clicking it again, I want the div to slide up (off the page) then change the button icon back to it's original state.

I have the div set to `display:none`, it slides down fine and the button changes icon but as soon as it slide into place it disappears! How can I stop that and also slide it up on clicking again?

Here's my attempt:

```
$('.menu-up').on('click', function(e) {
    $( ".icon-bar" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });

    $(this).toggleClass("menu-up menu-down")
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML code.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki It's just a standard button and a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** instead.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ngLofLzr/)**

```
$('.menu-up').on('click', function(e) {
    $( ".icon-bar" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $(this).toggleClass("menu-up menu-down")
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height to 0 instead of display: none.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a fiddle. Check it out, I used slideToggle instead of slideDown for your on click.

```
$( ".icon-bar" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/okbndfeL/